# What is nodejitsu hosting details for nodejs

Tags: node.js, web-hosting, nodejitsu

"A drone is an individual unit of computing power."

i cant understand what that means....
how much space?

incoming traffic per month?

outgoing?

ram?

Cpu?

internet speed?

I have searched their plans.
They say you get 1drone for 10 dollars a month.

Which doesn't tell me anything!

What does it mean to get 1 drone in terms of questions above? hoping someone here knows more about their hosting as it's well known provider for node.js.

Please word this question right if it feels weird..

Comment: Try this: https://www.nodejitsu.com/company/contact/

Comment: Same here. I get the impression that my app will speed up if I assign more drones to it. But I can't be sure if I have to change my code for it to be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejitsu gives you 2 GB of disk space, 256 MB of RAM, and unlimited traffic. The CPUs are 2.4 GHz Xeon processors.

As per Joyent's website:

> 10 Gbit/s and 40 Gbit/s networking standard

You can also scale up to 1 GB of RAM on business plans.

Comment: Is this documented online anywhere? I'd like to check if this is still correct.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't work for Nodejitsu anymore or use their platform. Join #nodejitsu on Freenode and they can probably help you better than I can. Sorry.